# Dr Racket problems with SICP

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket, sicp

I'm working through SICP. Currently, in the first chapter, I'm having problems getting Racket to let me redefine "primitives". For instance, I was under the impression that I should be able to arbitrarily do `(define + 5)` and that would be fine, or redefine the `sqrt` procedure. Instead, I get this:

```
define-values: cannot change constant variable: +
```

I have the language currently set to R5RS, which I was under the impression would take care of the compatibility issues with SICP.

Comment: This (define + 5) actually works on my machine (Ubuntu 12.04) with DrRacket 5.1.3 now. Did they change the default?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Even if possible, such redefinitions are not something that you should do without really understanding how the system will react to this.  For example, if you redefine `+`, will any other code break?  The answer to that in Racket's case is "no" -- but this is because you don't really get to redefine `+`: instead, you define a *new* `+`, which only your code can use.

As for the language choice -- Rackets R5RS mode is a very strict one, and it's not something that you'd usually want to use.  For a *much* more SICP-friendly environment, see Neil Van Dyke's [SICP Support page](http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket-sicp/) which will provide you with a language specifically made for the book.  (IIRC, it even has the graphical language that the books shows off.)

Comment: I actually ended up going ahead and installing Neil Van Dyke's package, so that I could have support for the picture language and for streams. Initially, I was just irritated that I couldn't work through some of the examples in the book. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

I ran into problems trying to work thru the RSA example here (part of the SICP stuff):
http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/psets/ps3/readme.html

To get this working I had to do this:

1) Run thru the initial download by adding this to the top of a blank file:

```
#lang planet neil/sicp
```

and then hitting "Run"

2) Enjoy DrRacket's very user friendly, automatic download and install the PLaneT Neil module by going to grab a coffee ;-)

3) And then once it is installed, close DrRacket.

4) Reopen, and choose SICP PLaneT 1.15 from the Choose A Language list.
(I could not get adding the declaration at the top to work for me aside from doing that to perform the initial download.)

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, in my office the site http://http://planet.racket-lang.org is blocked so i cannot download the SICP support module through DrRacket. Is there any way i can directly download the files and then manually install the files to DrRacket? Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

In the language panel, you need to disable "disallow redefinition of initial bindings." This fixes the issue.