# Scheme and Racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

Is there a big difference betwen the languages **Racket** and **Scheme**? In the book *[How to Design Programs](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/)* (HtDP2e) they teach you *Racket*, but in the famous *[SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)* it is *Scheme*. I am going to read these books simultaneously, what should I be aware of?

Comment: note: it was the first hit on "racket vs scheme". shame on you.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath "vs" is to strong for this purpose :)

Comment: Regardless of whether your question is an _exact_ duplicate of the one to which @KarolyHorvath linked, I doubt you'll get better answers than the ones you'll find there.

Comment: You can use Racket for both books, just take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597781/dr-racket-problems-with-sicp) for some advice on using DrRacket for SICP.

Comment: Actually, the book *How to Design Programs* does not teach Racket, but teaches program design using several teaching languages.

Comment: Stick with SICP; no reason to focus on a dialect.  That would be like learning to speak Italian with a Sicilian accent...

Answer (score 5):

SICP uses R4RS Scheme while HtDP uses a stripped down lexical Scheme-like language. Lang #racket is originally a R5RS with a propretary module system, but it has adopted some R6RS features as well as going their own way with their immutable pairs.